# Ruby empty array changes values in iterations because of another array

Tags: arrays, ruby

An empty array is defined outside a block and within the block, it is assigned to a new variable. If the new array changes, the empty array also modifies its values. Why?

```
# THIS CODE CHECK WHICH LETTERS IN klas APPEAR IN docs
klas = ["a", "b", "c"]

docs = [[1, "a"], [2, "a"], [3, "b"], [4, "b"], [5, "c"], [6, "c"]]

output = []
empty_array = Array.new(klas.size) { 0 } # EMPTY ARRAY DEFINED HERE

docs.each do |doc|
    puts empty_array.inspect
    puts (output_row = empty_array).inspect # EMPTY ARRAY ASSIGNED TO ANOTHER

    # FIND INDEX OF THE LETTER IN klas FROM docs. ASSIGN 1.
    output_row[klas.index(doc[1])] = 1 # PROBLEM! THIS ALSO CHANGES THE EMPTY ARRAY VALUES
    output << output_row
end
```

CONSOLE OUTPUT to show empty array changing its value based on another array

```
###
empty_array is [0, 0, 0]
output_row is [0, 0, 0]
---
###
empty_array is [1, 0, 0]
output_row is [1, 0, 0]
---
###
empty_array is [1, 0, 0]
output_row is [1, 0, 0]
---
###
empty_array is [1, 1, 0]
output_row is [1, 1, 0]
---
###
empty_array is [1, 1, 0]
output_row is [1, 1, 0]
---
###
empty_array is [1, 1, 1]
output_row is [1, 1, 1]
---

# INCORRECT output IS
=> [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
# SHOULD BE
=> [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1]]
```

But if the empty array is defined within the block and assigned to a new variable it works as expected.

```
docs.each do |doc|
    empty_array = Array.new(klas.size) { 0 } # THIS MAKES SURE empty_array stays with zero values
    output_row = empty_array    
    output_row[klas.index(doc[1])] = 1
    output << output_row
end

CORRECT output IS
=> [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1]]
```

Why is the empty array modifying its value when it is outside a block? Shouldn't it remain the same irrespective of another array changing its value?

Comment: "Shouldn't it remain the same irrespective of another array changing its value?" – There is no "another array". How many arrays did you create in that piece of code? One. Not two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using

```
output_row = empty_array
```

you are not copying the empty array. You are creating a reference to the same underlying array that is referenced in `empty_array`.

You can create a clone or a duplicate of the array. So use:

```
output_row = empty_array.dup
```

This will create a new Array, which is a duplicate of empty_array, see http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-dup

A more complete explanation on what happens with an example:

```
a = [1] => [1] # is creating a new array 'x'
               # a is referencing this array, a is not the array itself!

b = a   => [1] # b now references the array 'x'

a = [2] => [2] # is creating a new array 'y', a is referencing this new array
               # the reference of b is not changing

b       => [1] # b still pointing to array 'x'
```

So with `b = a` you just tell them to reference the same array `x`, but `b` is not a reference to `a`.

Comment: To check that suspicion I had tried this before posting
`irb(main):562:0> a = [1]
=> [1]
irb(main):563:0> b = a
=> [1]
irb(main):564:0> a = [2]
=> [2]
irb(main):565:0> b
=> [1]
irb(main):566:0> b = [3]
=> [3]
irb(main):567:0> a
=> [2]
`

Comment: But if its an array of more elements, `a = [0,0,0]` it changes it's value, like in the question. But by using `dup` as you suggested, it works as expected. Why is that? And why with simple values it does not behave differently?

Comment: I think I can explain. Stay tuned

Comment: Your test in the terminal was flawed, try it doing: `a = [1]`; `b = a`; `a[0] = 2`; `puts a`; `puts b` to show the error occurring. With your test, you reassigned `a` to a new array, decoupling it from `b` and then you did the same thing in reverse with `b`

Comment: Okay so targeting the index has the same effect! That needs some more explanation.

Comment: @SimpleLime Yeah but if its a complex array then, indexing it or not, have the same effect.

Comment: @arjun, I updated my answer. The problem is that you are misunderstanding as the variable `a` being the array, but a just points to an array, that exists somewhere in the memory. Have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: @RolandStuder Yup, an entirely new object is created.  Now it is obvious. Thanks

Comment: One thing - `empty_array.dup` is somewhat similar to `Array.new(empty_array)`?

Comment: _"Any change of one will be reflected in the other"_ – that sounds like there were two arrays which are being synchronized.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks, I edited that out. That part of the answer was written, before I fully understood what I was explaining :-)